# Correct way to handle a WIX warning: LGHT1076: ICE48

Tags: wix

I want to default a proptery in my wix installation to a hardcoded directory. Is there a "correct" way to encode a default value (note, this is an internal project, not something distributed to the public) so I don't get the following warning:

```
LGHT1076: ICE48 Directory 'FOO' appears to be hardcoded in the property table to a local drive.
```

The wix file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="22E1F223-E3AD-45F8-A394-1289AAAA64C8"
           Name="MyService"
           Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0"
           UpgradeCode="140F5A44-58DA-4364-876B-9D9484C04CD9">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="FOO" Value="C:\MyRootDirectory\" />
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have the same issue, we just live with the warning. In our scenario, it makes sense to hardcode the directory into the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow best practices ( I don't think you do here since  you mention it's an 'internal' installer )  you shouldn't ever hard code paths.  Choose a property like [`WindowsVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and design your application to be flexible if `WindowsVolume` happens to not be `C:`

If you really don't care about this, you can use a custom action to set the property to what you want at the very beginning of the install.  A simple Type 51 CA ( Set Property ) scheduled early on in both the UI and Execute Sequence will do the trick nicely.  This way the property doesn't have the offending value when validation runs but then gets the value right away at the beginning of the install.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to reference a certain directory in your directory tree as a property, then it is natively supported. Quoting MSDN, "[When the directories are resolved during the CostFinalize action, the keys in the Directory table become properties set to directory paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372452(VS.85).aspx)"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to get rid of this warning I chose to remove the default value from the property.
For example, this (no ICE48 warning):

```
<Property Id="VS2010INSTALLDIR">
    <RegistrySearch Id="VS2010_InstallDir" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0" Name="InstallDir" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

instead of this (ICE48 warning):

```
<Property Id="VS2010INSTALLDIR" Value="0">
    <RegistrySearch Id="VS2010_InstallDir" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0" Name="InstallDir" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<SetProperty>` in conjuction with `[WindowVolume]` element to solve that:

```
<Product>
  <!-- Define your property with an empty value -->
  <Property Id="FOO" Value=""/>

  <!-- Set property to your target value, using the WindowVolume built-in property -->
  <SetProperty Id="FOO" Value="[WindowVolume]\MyRootDirectory\"
               After="LaunchConditions"/>
</Product>
```